# Calling method over D-Bus fails if app must be started by D-Bus

Tags: go, systemd, dbus

Using golang I've developed 2 apps that can communicate through D-Bus.
App #1 is running as a background service but is not started at boot but only on-demand.
App #2 calls a method of app #1 using D-Bus.

Here's what's going on (none of the apps are running).

1. App #2 calls the app #1 method through D-Bus.
2. D-Bus starts app #1 using its systemd .service file.
3. App #3 fails and returns the error : `Object does not implement the interface 'com.mycompany.sysupdate'`

If I re-start app #2 it works since app #1 is still running in the background.

I can reproduce the same behavior using `dbus-send`. It fails if it needs to start app #1 but it works if app #1 is already running.

Here's the systemd .service file

```
[Unit]
Description=system update (sysupdate)
Requires=dbus.socket
After=dbus.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/sbin/sysupdate

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

App #1 calls [SdNotify("READY=1")](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html) after the update interface has been registered on DBus so systemd knows the service is ready.

I also tried to use the dbus type, but the result is the same.

```
Type=dbus
BusName=com.mycompany.sysupdate
```

Here's the DBus service file `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/com.mycompany.sysupdate.service`

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=com.mycompany.sysupdate
Exec=false
User=root
SystemdService=sysupdate.service
```

I was expecting D-Bus to wait for app #1 to be successfully started before calling the method.

Am I missing a point ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Comment: Don't point to an eight-year old question to try and refute the actual rule in the systemd tag.